# TypeScript define type is universal generic type

Tags: typescript

say we have code below:

```
  class Model<T> {
    constructor(public data: T) {}
  }

  class View<T extends Model<?>>{
    constructor(public model: T) {}
  }
```

I wanna define class `View` has a property `model` which is a `Model` type, however, `Model` is a generic type,I don't know what should I use as the type variable.

PS: is there any way better than `Model<any>`?

Comment: You can simplify it a bit. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0jlw)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine but then it would be tricky if I define some class derived from Model and View.  [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO0DeAoZZYAEwC4QBXAWwCNo8BfPPBAGzk02QFkB7YiKwA8AFQB8yfIQS8QmMFAoIwvKAAoADhRqtgCZMThg4pZCICUk5EyYt2nZFmjIIAD0ghiXPgOEZsUGJSyADmEGCoxGrm5NR0UMGEUOEUUCDIYAAWwJgAdIbGuSQE1ozMbBxcAGrAEADuokElMnIKSirqWjp6yFT8gqY+go2WOKW2FQ5OUAAKcGEu7hCe1bUN-tBNScsC6uaJyAD0hy5QUKolhMfIcJ5oyHW3IHAGEDCgKFkofb5EXIhgChwVisACeN0cAQyoI0KBoFDAyBAvERQz80zEl2QyUBaWQAANppFSAASHBZHK5H6CXJhCJRcwMfElGzMIA)

Comment: Please provide an example of how you want to call/create UserPage object

Comment: `IUser` != `User` - You'll need to specify which model you're using: `class UserPage extends View<**User**>`

Answer (score 2):

`unknown` exists for this use case. As it is technically `unknown` at this point in time what generic type `Model` will get.

`unknown` is the typesafe counterpart of `any`. Anything can be assigned to `unknown`. But `unknown` itself cannot be assigned to anything without an explicit assertion.

```
class View<T extends Model<unknown>>{
  constructor(public model: T) {}
}
```